# Video Player API for e-Learning Application

Tags: api, video-streaming

I am creating an affordable on-line learning website for local students. I need guidance on the video API or plugins that best fit for this purpose. I am looking for video players that are available in the Udemy app or any other similar website.

Comment: How would we know what is best fit for your site if you haven't given a single criteria? Also, asking for us to suggest software, apis etc. is off topic

Comment: @JamesZ I mentioned Apps like Udemy and other similar apps. What type of technology or APIs do these apps use?